# Get results by count and operators in one query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreach, count

I think question is wrong, but i don't know how to ask properly.

This query selects all businesses with all workers, whose `job_types` contains `C` letter.

```
$connect = DB::table('relationship')
->join('workers', 'workers.id', '=', 'relationship.w_id')
->join('business', 'business.id', '=', 'relationship.b_id')
->whereRaw('job_types LIKE "%C%"')
->groupBy('relationship.w_id')
->get();
```

I am using foreach for displaying results

```
foreach ($connect as $item) {
 echo $item->name;
 // etc
}
```

I want to select all businesses who have more than 3 or less than 3 or equal to 3 (depends of what i need) `job_types LIKE "%C%"` and store information like that:

```
1. APPLE | Tom | C
2. APPLE | Tim | C
3. APPLE | Jeff | C
4. IBM | Jenny | C
5. IBM | Sean | C
6. IBM | Ian | C
// etc``
```

Answer by **@KikiTheOne** is kinda working, but it does not display results as needed.

Comment: Well what column contains the worker count?

Then just do `worker_count > 5` in the whereRaw for greater than 5 etc.

Comment: There is no column for storing counts in database

Comment: @MattCowley I Guess there is a Worker Table and a Businesstable and a Real table. in the realtable ia like workerA | Busines B.  u have to Group by b_id and Count(workers) in ur first join.

Comment: why not just `->where('job_types', 'like', '%C%')` instead of `->whereRaw()`?

Comment: @Neat because real query is more complex than here. Here i posted only small, readable query.

Comment: @KikiTheOne Ah yeah, so Count() of some kind would be what is needed then.

Having the structure of the tables would be helpful ;)

Comment: @MattCowley there is ``workers`` and ``business`` tables. Also ``relationship`` table, for connecting both of them

Comment: @Tauras why not just use the relationship table and Group by Business ?

Comment: @KikiTheOne does grouping by workers is wrong? If you have an idea, please share.

Comment: @Tauras how should this happen ? i cant Group TIM and TOM :) but i can Count them. this is an n:m relation ( 1 worker can work for multiple businesses , and 1 Business can have multiple workers )

Comment: @Tauras Thats a Clean SQL u can adapt to ur Code  `SELECT count(t1.w_id),t1.b_id,t3.name FROM SO_RELATIONSHIP as t1 inner join SO_BUSINESS as t3 on t1.b_id = t3.id GROUP BY t1.b_id ` t3.name i just added a Business Name for it

Comment: @KikiTheOne so, i was trying to implement your code to my code, and it kinda worked, kinda no. Same as answer from @Pradyut Manna . It is working, but it looks like operator does not working, because it gives me not correct results. For example, if i set ``workers_count < 3`` it still returns businesses with for example 6 workers.

Comment: when i am home from work i might contact u in Chat or post an answer here when i have more time to try this again :)

Comment: @KikiTheOne okay. I will wait for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125596/discussion-between-kikitheone-and-tauras).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *****SOLUTION*****

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
    people_details as t1 
inner join 
    people_branches as t2 
on t1.id = t2.id 
    inner join 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            count(t1.id) as worker_counter,t1.branch_id
        FROM 
            people_branches as t1 
                inner join people_details as t2 
                    on t1.id = t2.id 
        WHERE 
            t2.job_types LIKE '%C%' 
            group by branch_id 
    ) as t3 
    on t2.branch_id = t3.branch_id 
inner join people_frontpage as t4 
    on t4.id = t1.id 
inner join business as t5 
    on t5.id = t2.branch_id 
WHERE 
    t1.job_types LIKE '%C%' 
    AND t3.worker_counter > 200
```

### ----------

---

### **OLD - UPDATE**

1. [image: Table Business]
2. [image: Table Relationship]
3. [image: Table Worker]
4. [image: Output]

---

```
SELECT 
    t3.bus_name, t1.name, t1.job_types 
FROM 
    SO_WORKER as t1 
    inner join 
        SO_RELATIONSHIP as t2 
            on t1.id = t2.w_id 
    inner join 
    (
        SELECT 
            count(t1.w_id) as worker_counter,t1.b_id,t3.bus_name 
        FROM 
            SO_RELATIONSHIP as t1 
            inner join SO_WORKER as t2 
                on t1.w_id = t2.id 
            inner join SO_BUSINESS as t3 
                on t3.id = t1.b_id 
        WHERE 
            t2.job_types LIKE '%C%' 
            group by b_id
    ) as t3 
    on t2.b_id = t3.b_id 
WHERE t1.job_types LIKE '%C%'
AND t3.worker_counter <= 3
```

Unformated

```
SELECT t3.bus_name, t1.name, t1.job_types FROM SO_WORKER as t1 inner join SO_RELATIONSHIP as t2 on t1.id = t2.w_id inner join (SELECT count(t1.w_id) as worker_counter,t1.b_id,t3.bus_name FROM SO_RELATIONSHIP as t1 inner join SO_WORKER as t2 on t1.w_id = t2.id inner join SO_BUSINESS as t3 on t3.id = t1.b_id WHERE t2.job_types LIKE '%C%' group by b_id) as t3 on t2.b_id = t3.b_id WHERE t1.job_types LIKE '%C%' AND t3.worker_counter <= 3
```

### --------------------------------------------------

***OLD CODE***

in Relation to the **comments** from Post 1.

```
Table: SO_BUSINESS
    id      |       bus_name
    --------------------
    1       |       BUSI A
    2       |       BUSI B

Table: SO_WORKER
    id      |       job_types
    ---------------------
    1       |       CEO
    2       |       GFO
    3       |       CTO
    4       |       Manager
    5       |       Worker

Table: SO_RELATIONSHIP
    w_id    |       b_id
    ----------------
    1       |       1
    2       |       2
    3       |       1
    4       |       1
    5       |       2

Query: Output
    workers_count   |       b_id        |       bus_name
    --------------------------------------------
    2               |       1           |       BUSI A
```

.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            count(t1.w_id) as workers_count,
            t1.b_id,
            t3.bus_name
        FROM 
            SO_RELATIONSHIP as t1 
            inner join 
                SO_WORKER as t2 on t1.w_id = t2.id 
            inner join 
                SO_BUSINESS as t3 on t1.b_id = t3.id 
        WHERE 
            t2.job_types LIKE '%C%' 
        GROUP BY t1.b_id
    ) as t4 
WHERE 
    t4.workers_count < 3
```

Code unformated:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT count(t1.w_id) as workers_count,t1.b_id,t3.bus_name FROM SO_RELATIONSHIP as t1 inner join SO_WORKER as t2 on t1.w_id = t2.id inner join SO_BUSINESS as t3 on t1.b_id = t3.id WHERE t2.job_types LIKE '%C%' GROUP BY t1.b_id) as t4 WHERE t4.workers_count < 3
```

**Let me know if this helps u**

Comment: Good morning. So, relationship table, has these fields: ``1. r_id (for auto increment) 2. b_id 3. w_id`` . I will try your code now

Comment: Looks like, that your code is working perfectly, but i have one, last question. For example: ``t4.workers_count = 3`` displays one row only, if that business has 3 workers with ``"%C%"``. How to duplicate that business name 3 times and store those 3 workers info? Your query works pefectly, but this small change will make this query legendary.

Comment: Looks like i made this myself by changing ``group by`` and for validation i added ``order by name``. Thanks, leets keep on touch for this one, if possible.

Comment: Okay, so the problem still exists, cant figure it out, how to display correct results. If ``t4.wokers_count = 3`` it shows all businesses who has 3 workers with ``"%C%"``. How to duplicate founded business 3 times and show informacion for one worker in each duplicated row. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = DB::table('relationship')
->join('workers', 'workers.id', '=', 'relationship.w_id')
->join('business', 'business.id', '=', 'relationship.b_id')
->selectRaw('workers.*,business.*,(select count(*) from workers where job_types like "%c%") as workers_count')
->where('job_types', 'like', '%C%')
->having('workers_count','>=',5)
->groupBy('relationship.w_id')
->get();
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake in selectRaw line. No quotes

Comment: Sorry, it gives me an error for wrong SQL syntax. ``You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)``.

Comment: It is working, but it looks like operator does not working, because it gives me not correct results. For example, if i set ``workers_count < 3`` it still returns businesses with for example 6 workers.